# AnimationDrawable release bitmaps, then reload them again

Tags: java, android, bitmap

In my app I have a `AnimationDrawable`, and XML for it with quite many images (here I show just 3 for example).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:oneshot="true">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/anim1" android:duration="180" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/anim2" android:duration="60" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/anim3" android:duration="60" />
</animation-list>
```

My AnimationDrawable is called generally rarely in my app, like once per session or not even called, but it can also be called more times per session.
So I decided to clear bitmap images after displaying this AnimationDrawable, so they aren't in memory (that would be useless, because in 90% it probably won't be used again in current launch).
I'm using following code to clear it from memory:

```
void releaseAnimationDrawable(AnimationDrawable ad)
   {
        ad.stop();
        for (int i = 0; i < ad.getNumberOfFrames(); ++i){
            Drawable frame = ad.getFrame(i);
            if (frame instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
                ((BitmapDrawable)frame).getBitmap().recycle();
            }
            frame.setCallback(null);
        }

        ad.setCallback(null); 
   }
```

But..
When I use this AnimationDrawable once, then release it with code above, and later try to create it again, I'm getting error:

```
Cannot draw recycled bitmaps
```

---

I'm getting animation every time with:

```
animationDrawable = (AnimationDrawable) myView.getBackground(); // view bg is xml sequence of images I've mentioned above
```

---

I think there's problem because Android don't want to create bitmaps with same width and height again, so it tries to use the old bitmap - but that's already recycled.

All I want is to create new `AnimationDrawable` each time. How to do that, and not "reuse" the recycled one?